# Is there a Firefox/chrome plugin, or a software that disables specific terms from being searched for in google?

Tags: web-filtering

Family protection software are good, however, they are NOT smart enough, more specifically, in filtering other languages than English's pornography search keywords.

Answer (score 0):

I doubt there's something like this, plus there are other search engines so a Google-specific solution might not be effective in any case. Perhaps you can set up **OpenDNS** and try their [**FamilyShield**](http://www.opendns.com/home-solutions/parental-controls#family) service, which is free:

> **Instantly blocks access to adult websites. No complicated configuration.**
>
> FamilyShield is pre-configured to block adult websites across your Internet connection.  Just turn it on and go.  The filter is always up-to-date, adding new sites 24/7.
>
> **Flexible parental controls that protect every Internet-connected device in your home, instantly.**
>
> When you set up FamilyShield on your router, every device in your home gets protected. That means everything: your kids' Xbox, Playstation, Wii, DS, iPad, and even their iPhone. [Learn more](http://www.opendns.com/parental-controls).